# Why did I receive rep points after answer accepted, even though already hit 200 rep cap?

Tags: support, reputation

I know I can only receive 200 reputation points per day.

So today I notived that I received upvotes but no reputation points.

Suddenly I DID receive points, because my answer was accepted.

How did that happen? I looked for help (https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) but no explaination there.

Can anyone explain? And where could I have found/read it?

Comment: The 200 limit only applies to votes. Accepts (among others) are exempt.

Comment: I won't call +355 no reputation points...

Comment: Marking this as duplicate assumes people will read the entire FAQ entry and note the third bullet under the Additionally header.  Doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: A lot of questions are closed as duplicates when they don't show if they ever saw the canonical question in the first place @and

Answer (score 5):

Bounties and accepts are exempt from the daily reputation limit.

See the "Additionally" section under of [the answer to "How does Reputation work"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/203389)

Comment: Is this really necessary to answer? A close vote (with a link to where this answer is from, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)) would be better, no?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII *shrug*.. IDK. People do it all the time on meta. It's not preferable on a main site though..

Comment: Thanx! That other post is quit clear. My second question where could I have read that in the official manuals?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII that's a lot of information to parse out when Seth just answered in one sentence instead of redirecting the OP to more research.  That's pretty consistent with non-meta SO anyway - faster information is preferable.

Comment: @djechlin no, it isn't preferable. Duplicate answers really don't add anything to the site, when a single click can get you the information you need, and more.

Comment: @djechlin A quick summary can go in a comment as well. I guess there's no sense in being pedantic about it, but keeping dupe questions from having upvoted answers helps them get deleted faster and keeps information centralised.

Comment: @Asad I didn't think we wanted to delete duplicates..

Comment: @Asad firstly we don't want to delete duplicates.  Secondly they're not duplicates (now that I've made the question title precise).  "Why did I receive rep on an answer accept after reaching rep cap?" Is not the same question as "please summarize all rep rules."  That's like saying "What's the cause of this compile error?" is a dupe of "The Java Language Specification."  Seth's answer is completely correct - summary with link to original source.